# How to trade with another player?

Tags: guild-wars-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Person to Person Trading in Guild Wars 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64655/person-to-person-trading-in-guild-wars-2)

I cant seem to find the option for a trade. Where is it in the UI of Guild Wars 2?

The player menu has add friend and add to party, but the trade option seems to be missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no system player-to-player trading in Guild Wars 2. The only way to trade is to use the auction house. It is possible to exchange gold and items via mail, but there's no way to guarantee the person you're trading with will actually send you the gold/items you agreed on.